# Positive apparatus with reledmac

Tags: reledmac

I'd like to provide a positive apparatus for a text I edited and I'm now trying to typeset with LuaLaTeX and reledmac. In order to achieve this I'm manually editing the lemma for each `\edtext` to print the *sigla* of the manuscripts that pass down the accepted *lectio* before the bracket, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Lorem ipsum dolor sit \edtext{amet}{\lemma{amet \textit{A B}}\Afootnote{emet \textit{C}}}, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam suscipit fermentum risus, ut consequat massa ornare non. In vitae faucibus risus, eu tempor urna. Vivamus ac metus orci. Etiam eget nunc ex. Vestibulum quis diam sit amet orci sollicitudin laoreet ut et nulla. Praesent maximus sagittis dolor, a faucibus orci sagittis fermentum.
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

[image]

The drawback of this method is that the whole edition is quite long, so repeating the same text twice everytime in the `\edtext` and the subsequent `\lemma` is not really ideal.

Since I coundn't find anything predefined in the extensive reledmac's documentation, is there any way (even a custom macro) to provide each time only the *sigla* and then have it printed before the bracket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to understand is that reledmac is neutral regarding the content of the critical footnote. It can be a textual apparatus, but also anything else.

Consequently, reledmac does not knwo anything about the manuscripts (except regarding the apparatus siglium).

Each author have to define his/her own command to deal with the content of the notes.

In your case, you could create such command

```
% #1 Ms with the lemma
% #2 Lemma
% #3 Variants
\newcommand{\apparatus}[3]{\edtext{#2}{\lemma{#2 #1}\Afootnote{#3}}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your help (and for your great package).